# ActiveDirectory DNS - web based management

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

Can anyone recommend a web based tool for managing/viewing DNS records in an active directory environment?   Something like ProBIND, but for a microsoft shop?

Comment: I havent found any formal projects, but did find this http://forums.asp.net/t/589684.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The GUI in Windows is so straightforward that there probably isn't a big market for web-based tools. I'm sure there's something out there somewhere...but I've never heard of it.

Comment: +1 on the question because I feel it would be awfully convenient to be able to do dsa.msc/gpmc.msc stuff from within a web browser on a non-Windows OS.

Comment: If I really needed a web version of the gui I'd publish the gui to the web with terminal services...

Answer (score 1):

Using a scheduled task you can use netsh to export the dhcp info to a csv. I then import this using datatables to easily display and filter by mac / ip / hostname. These files are all saved on a webserver / directory that is a website and users can go to this page to view the dhcp info. Its read only and "out of sync" by however long your scheduled task repeats but I have used this to good effect. The benefit of netsh is you can query Windows DHCP servers in remote sites / subnets also and report back to a central server.

Answer (score 0):

Try Infoblox's IPAM Winconnect product. http://www.infoblox.com/products/ipam-winconnect.cfm

I must admit, I haven't tried this, but their Enterprise Appliance Solutions are very feature-rich, robust and solid.

Good Luck.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to use an appliance, just a simple web-based intranet tool.
Well at least, its a start, thanks

Comment: if your on an intranet why would you even want to use a web based tool?

Comment: @Jim Maybe they want to access the application from a non-Windows OS? Handheld network-connected devices (e.g. Blackberry, iPod Touch) are also becoming quite popular.

Comment: @jscott point taken- I'm not sure I'd want the backbone of my active directory to be managed by a third party tool